# avoid duplicate data when use left join

Tags: sql, duplicates, left-join

**Table Contents**

```
**6_izin_plani**     **akis**        ` **ARTCRAFT_IZIN**`

`izin_baslangic`    `akis_id`         `kys_id`
`izin_bitis`        `kullanici_id`    `kullanici_id`
`akis_id`           `pozisyon_id`     `izin_bastar`
`izin_sure`                           `izin_bittar`
```

I have 3 different tables and 6_izin_plani, akis are at gurok database. ARTCRAFT_IZIN is at guralcam database.

```
**My SQLquery** 
 $sql = "select pl*, a.kullanici_id ad, if(i.izin_bastar >='1530423000' and 
         i.izin_bittar <='1546407000',kys_id,'') from 6_izin_plani pl join 
         akis a on pl.akis_id=a.akis_id  left join guralcam.ARTCRAFT_IZIN i 
         on i.kullanici_id = a.kullanici_id 
         where pl.izin_baslangic >='1530423000' and 
         pl.izin_bitis<='1546407000'

**Result** 


akis_id `kullanici_id` `izin_baslangic` `kys_id`  `izin_bastar`
133593  `hcavsi`        `15.06.2018`     `11451`   `12.08.2018`
133593  `hcavsi`        `20.08.2018`     `11451`   `12.08.2018`
133594  `abulut`        `12.02.2018`     `11452`   `10.05.2018` 
133594  `abulut`        `19.05.2018`     `11452`   `10.05.2018`
```

kys_id and izin_bastar have one register at table. I want to print one time at table. So if kys_id and izin_bastar have the same values, I just want to print kys_id and izin_bastar one time. How can I do?

**akis_id** is primary_key for akis table and 6_izin_plani table. 
**kys_id** is primary_key for ARTCRAFT_IZIN table.

Comment: It is not clear what result you are after. It would probably help if you added some more rows to your example and showed the desired result, too. What are the table's unique keys? (Well it's `akis_id` for the `akis` table obviously, but what about the other tables?)

Comment: [mcve] please including more words/sentences explaining.

Comment: You say that `kys_id` is the primary_key of `artcraft_izin`. So for one `kys_id` you get exactly one `izin_bastar` and one `kullanici_id` of course. However, there is an n:m relation between `artcraft_izin` and `akis`, so you can get various `akis_id` per `kys_id`. You say you want to show one row per `kys_id`, but you want to show a `akis_id`, too. Which? The greatest? The least? Just any?

Comment: Then you say that the primary key for `6_izin_plani` is `akis_id`. That is surprising. Why have two tables then and not put `izin_baslangic`, `izin_bitis`, and `izin_sure` in `akis` directly? Anyway, for one `kys_id` you'll get multiple `izin_baslangic`. So again: If you only want to show one row per `kys_id`, which `izin_baslangic` do you want to show?